# Ajax não retorna para view utilizando find()

Tags: jquery, ajax

Olá, estou criando um ajax porem se eu uso o find para retorna na div desejada ele não retorna

```
success: function (ret) {
            if (ret == "sucesso") {
                $(this).find(".msg-envio").html("<p class='msg-sucesso'>Orçamento enviado com sucesso!</p>");
            }
            else {
                $(this).find(".msg-envio").html("<p class='msg-erro'>Houve um erro ao enviar o orçamento.</p>");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `this` dentro do ajax está noutro escopo. Tens de criar uma variável para guardar essa referência pois o ajax atribui outra coisa ao `this`.

Colocaste pouco código por isso deixo um exemplo aproximado ao teu código:

```
// antes do ajax
var self = this; // <-- aqui guardas a referência
$.ajax({
    // etc
    success: function (ret) {
        if (ret == "sucesso") {
            $(self).find(".msg-envio").html("<p class='msg-sucesso'>Orçamento enviado com sucesso!</p>");
        }
        else {
            $(self).find(".msg-envio").html("<p class='msg-erro'>Houve um erro ao enviar o orçamento.</p>");
        }
    }
// etc...
```

Existe contudo uma opção para forçar a usar o `this` em que o ajax é chamado, nesse caso, em vez de fazeres como coloquei em cima, adiciona isto no objeto passado ao ajax:

```
context: this,
```

Comment: Funcionou Sergio, não sabia que o this ficava neutro dentro do ajax, Obg.

Comment: @BrendolL. ótimo que funcionou. Juntei mais uma alternativa agora para completar.

Comment: Apenas para informar. Reduza o máximo possível o escopo de busca do `find()`, ele é custoso, pois varre por todo DOM em busca de _matches_. Se vc souber onde está seu `.msg_envio`, restrinja a busca. Ex: `$('#divQueContemMsgEnvio').find('.msg_envio')` já irá reduzir o escopo da busca. Ou trocar um `find()` por um id `$('#id_msg_envio')` é muito performático.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi bem visto. Aliás (Brendol L.) esse elemento `$(self).find(".msg-envio")` devia ser posto em cache, para não teres de chamar o seletor a cada pedido ajax.